# Why is MSVC10 ignoring my #pragma warning(disable: 4251)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

So the 4251 warning is a serious base of at least microsoft's compiler. Essentially, any time you use a template class or non-dllexport class anywhere in the header definition you will get this warning. Better yet, there are numerous classes in stl (like map) where you can't even get rid of this error, period.

My problem is, is that for a specific class, the "#pragma warning(disable: 4251)" just flat out isn't working. It is working everywhere else but here.

DelWestInspectionProgram.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma warning(disable: 4251)
...

Output Log:
E:\svn\VisionNow\VisionSuite\VI.Inspector.ImageProcessing.Common\BIImage.h(79): warning       C4251: 'BIImage::_data' : class 'boost::shared_array<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be   used by clients of class 'BIImage'
6>          with
6>          [
6>              T=unsigned char
6>          ]
6>E:\svn\VisionNow\VisionSuite\VI.Inspector.ImageProcessing.Operators\BIImageOperator.h(25): warning C4251: 'BIImageOperator::_savePath' : class 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'BIImageOperator'
6>          with
6>          [
6>              _Elem=char,
6>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
6>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
6>          ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you put the #pragma in the header file which is causing the warning? Also, if the header file is being precompiled, you may need to rebuild your precompiled header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience there are two issues: when it is a DLL import and when it is a DLL export.

1. Where it is the dllexport, Microsoft seems to ignore the #pragma warning but this is just the one project so easy to put into the compiler settings to ignore this warning. I found if you put it there, Microsoft does not issue the warning.
2. Where it is the dllimport, i.e. the file using your header. I found there Microsoft does not ignore the pragma and does not issue the warning, so putting it in both places will fix your issue.

My guess is that the 79 projects that suppress the warning fine are those ones that are not the DLL itself.

1. The warning is probably there for a reason, that being that if your client library is using a different version of boost, or even a different compiler setting, it might break.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know that the warning is probably there for a reason, but using any kind of template code makes that warning more like a swarm of flies (annoying and makes other issues hard to identify) than it is itself a serious threat.

Comment: If you put the #pragma into your headers to suppress the warning, it is "polite" to use #pragma push and #pragma pop around it so it remains local to only your own files and does not intrude into other headers where you may wish to keep the warning.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, some errors cannot be disabled. It is that way with the Linker. Therefore I would assume it is the same way with some compiler too. But in general I would put it inside your stdafx.h file, or at least before it. Putting it after doesn't guarantee anything, especially since we can't see your code.

[EDIT]

On the other hand that is a serious warning that I would fix if I were you and not just ignore it. If you search here on stack overflow you will find some great discussions about why it is a problem.

Comment: Anything placed before `#include "stdafx.h"` will be ignored. Best to place it at the start of stdafx.h itself.

Comment: I can't really post any more code because 79 of the 80 projects suppress the warning fine, I just can't seem to get that last one to. I haven't really seen any serious discussion about the warning, and I also know that there are certain STL templates that cannot be exported, like map. If you have any links to good discussion about it, I would be happy to read them.